# Tossing an unfair coin with some probability and what is the minimum number of tosses to get 2 tails in a row?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

What is the least amount of times we need to toss the coin so that with at least 
chance we obtain tails in a row?

We have an unfair die with some probability, head with 3/8 and tail with 5/8

My question is,

If we toss 4 times, then we have some cases when we get two tails in a row.

For instance, HHTT is one option.

If I get TT on the first two trials, do I also have to consider the remaining two outcomes? TTHH, TTTH, TTTT ?

I am not sure whether we have to get exactly two tails in a row or we could have more than 2 tails in a row

Comment: The wording of the question is not completely clear. My interpretation, but it is only an interpretation, is what is the least number $n$ such that if we toss the coin $n$ times, the probability of *at least* two tails in a row is *at least* $1/2$.

Comment: So if we toss 4 coins, it could be TTHH,TTTH,TTTT?

Comment: That is my interpretation. But the wording really is somewhat confusing.  If it is an assignment, one might seek clarification from the instructor. "At least chance" also does not have an entirely clear meaning.

Comment: Are you sure you were not asked to find the "*expected* number of tosses"?

Comment: yes,, it just says minimum number of tosses.. I am completely stuck